# get row by criteria from PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query `select * from func1(ID)`

If I do: `select * from func1(10)`

I get:

```
rownum  date    qty
1       1.1.10  -5
2       1.10.10  6
3       2.10.10  6
4       5.10.10  -2
5       6.10.10  -8
```

If I do `select * from func1(7)`
I get

```
rownum  date qty
1       1.1.10  -7
2       1.10.10  -6
```

If I do `select * from func1(6)`
I get

```
rownum  date qty
```

`rownum` is the order of the column its being calculated in `func1()` based on my needs (it's not random numbering) you assume that the numbering is correct.

I want to write a query which returns me that find the first appears of `qty>=0` in `qty` (search from bottom up! from highest `rownum` to lowest) and gives me the `date` in the `rownum+1` row. If no rows match for `qty>=0` it will return the date of the 1st row. If no rows at all return `NULL`.

meaning that for:

`select * from func1(10)`   the output should be `5.10.10` (as rownum=3 is the first qty>=0 from bottom up and 5.10.10 is the date in the rownum+1)

`select * from func1(7)`   the output should be `1.1.10` (as there are no qty>=0 so it gives the date of the rownum=1)

`select * from func1(7)`   the output should be `NULL` (as there are no rows)

How can i do that?

Comment: please popuilate query inside `func()` instead...

Comment: @VaoTsun I don't want to modify func1() I want to write a query that uses it to give me the date i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first not negative from the bottom

```
t=# with a(i,q) as (values(1,-5),(2,3),(3,-9),(4,-1))
select * from a where i=1 or q>=0 order by case when i=1 then null else i end desc nulls last, q limit 1;
 i | q
---+---
 2 | 3
(1 row)
```

all negatives - first row:

```
t=# with a(i,q) as (values(1,-5),(2,-3),(3,-9),(4,-1))
select * from a where i=1 or q>=0 order by case when i=1 then null else i end desc nulls last, q limit 1;
 i | q
---+----
 1 | -5
(1 row)
```

empty set:

```
t=# with a(i,q) as (select 1,1 where false)
select * from a where i=1 or q>=0 order by case when i=1 then null else i end desc nulls last, q limit 1;
 i | q
---+---
(0 rows)
```